# Duplicate of closed question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

[Why do bosons and fermions exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/212589/why-do-bosons-and-fermions-exist) (or, question A) is currently nominated to be closed as a duplicate of [Why must fermions be antisymmetric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207459/why-must-fermions-be-antisymmetric) (question B). This seems fair at first glance, since the questions are quite similar and there's a reasonable answer at B.

However, question B is also closed.  If A is also closed, it won't be possible for normal mortals to add answers to either question.  Seems like a squicky way of avoiding answering a question at all, rather than a useful way to consolidate information.

Is there some guideline on closing one question as a duplicate of another question, which is also already closed?